# Rendering logout and Profile when the user is logged in in Next.js

Tags: next.js

I've created an api that will check if the user has a token in their cookies, if they do, that means they are logged in, meaning the profile link and logout button should be rendered, and if they are not logged in then the login and create account should be rendered. As of right now when the user logs out my code works as it automatically renders the create account and login links, but when the user logs in its not rendering the profile and logout button until the user refreshes the page and im not sure why.

Heres my code for my Header/navbar:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useAuth } from '@/app/authContext';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import Link from 'next/link';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Header() {
  const [isMobileMenuOpen, setIsMobileMenuOpen] = useState(false);
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false); 
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    grabEmail();
  }, []);

  const grabEmail = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('api/users/grabUserEmail');
      setIsLoggedIn(true); 
    } catch (error) {
      setIsLoggedIn(false); 
    }
  };

  const toggleMobileMenu = () => {
    setIsMobileMenuOpen(!isMobileMenuOpen);
  };

  const handleMenuItemClick = () => {
    setIsMobileMenuOpen(false);
  };

  const handleLogout = () => {
    setShowModal(true);
  };

  const confirmLogout = async () => {
    try {
      await axios.get('/api/users/logout');
      setIsLoggedIn(false); 
      setIsMobileMenuOpen(false); 
      router.push('/');
      setShowModal(false); 
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error logging out:", error);
    }
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    setShowModal(false); 
  };

  return (
    <header className='bg-white border-b flex justify-between p-4'>
      <div className="flex items-center gap-6">
        <Link href={'/'}>FashionFinder </Link>
        <nav className='hidden md:flex gap-4'>
          <Link href={'/about'}>About</Link>
          <Link href={'/contact'}>Contact Us</Link>
          <Link href={'/albums'}>Albums</Link>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div className="relative md:hidden">
        <button
          id="menu-toggle"
          className="outline-none focus:outline-none"
          onClick={toggleMobileMenu}
        >
          <svg
            className="w-6 h-6"
            fill="none"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            stroke="currentColor"
          >
            <path
              strokeLinecap="round"
              strokeLinejoin="round"
              strokeWidth="2"
              d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16"
            ></path>
          </svg>
        </button>
        {isMobileMenuOpen && (
          <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-700 bg-opacity-50 overflow-y-auto z-50">
            <div className="fixed top-0 right-0 w-1/2 h-screen bg-gray-800 flex flex-col items-center justify-center overflow-y-auto">
              <button
                className="absolute top-4 left-4 outline-none focus:outline-none"
                onClick={toggleMobileMenu}
              >
                <svg
                  className="w-6 h-6 text-white"
                  fill="none"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  stroke="currentColor"
                >
                  <path
                    strokeLinecap="round"
                    strokeLinejoin="round"
                    strokeWidth="2"
                    d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"
                  />
                </svg>
              </button>
              <nav className="flex flex-col items-center gap-4 text-white">
                <Link href="/about" onClick={handleMenuItemClick}>About</Link>
                <Link href="/contact" onClick={handleMenuItemClick}>Contact</Link>
                <Link href="/albums" onClick={handleMenuItemClick}>Albums</Link>
                {isLoggedIn ? (
                  <>
                    <Link href="/profile" onClick={handleMenuItemClick}>Profile</Link>
                    <button
                      onClick={handleLogout}
                      className="text-white"
                    >
                      Logout
                    </button>
                    
                  </>
                ) : (
                  <>
                    <Link href="/login" onClick={handleMenuItemClick}>Sign In</Link>
                    <Link href="/register" onClick={handleMenuItemClick}>Create Account</Link>
                  </>
                )}
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
      {/* Full-screen logout modal */}
      {showModal && (
        <div className="fixed inset-0 flex items-center justify-center z-50 bg-gray-700 bg-opacity-50">
          <div className="bg-white p-10 rounded-md shadow-lg">
            <h2 className="text-lg font-semibold mb-4">Are you sure you want to logout?</h2>
            <div className="flex items-center justify-center">
              <button
                className="bg-black text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-md mr-2 font-semibold"
                onClick={confirmLogout}
              >
                Yes
              </button>
              <button
                className="bg-gray-300 text-gray-800 px-4 py-2 rounded-md font-semibold"
                onClick={closeModal}
              >
                No
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
      <nav className='hidden md:flex items-center gap-4'>
        {isLoggedIn ? (
          <>
            <Link href={'/profile'}>Profile</Link>
            <button
              onClick={handleLogout}
              className="bg-black text-white px-6 py-3 rounded-lg font-semibold text-lg"
            >
              Logout
            </button>
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Link href={'/login'}>Sign In</Link>
            <Link href={'/register'}>Create Account</Link>
          </>
        )}
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
}
```

Comment: You say that you check for the user's cookie, but nowhere in the code snippet you shared there is a check made for cookie. It seems that everything hang on whether `grabUserEmail` will fail or not. Not sure where you are going with this.